# Using Word VBA to automate Excel, I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch when using the .Find function

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to get data from an excel sheet to a word document. I try using the 'Find' function however I keep getting the same error "Type mismatch" on this line:

```
Set FoundRange = .Cells.Find(260707)
```

Here is the subroutine I am running.

```
    Sub GetID()
Dim oXL As Object
Dim oWB As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String
Dim FoundRange As Range
Dim dummyvar As String

'Start a new instance of Excel
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Line to make Excel Visible or not
oXL.Visible = False
'Open the workbook
'Set the file path to access the 'Certified Personnel' table
WorkbookToWorkOn = "\\DataSource\CertifiedPersonnel.xlsx"
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
Set oSheet = oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("tblCertifiedPersonnel")
'End of Excel Automation. Everything from this point on can reference Excel.

With oSheet
    dummyvar = .Cells(1, 2).Text
    .Cells(1, 2).Select
    'Set the range of the cell containing the ID number
     'If the ID was found
    Set FoundRange = .Cells.Find(260707)

    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        'Set the NTlogin equal to the value of column 1, and row corresponding to the FoundRange row
        NTlogin = .Cells(FoundRange.Rows, 1).Text
        Role = .Cells(FoundRange.Rows, 4).Text
    End If
End With

'End Excel reference
oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
oXL.Application.Quit
Set oXL = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing


End Sub
```

I know it is accessing the correct workbook, because the dummy variable (dummyvar) is returning the value I expect. I have tried several things related to the 'Find' function, however I have not been able to get it to work. Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Try `.Cells.Find("260707")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using late binding and have `FoundRange` declared as a `Range`.  Since this is in a Word document, you're implicitly declaring it as a `Word.Range` here:

```
Dim FoundRange As Range
```

`.Find` is returning an `Excel.Range`. Change it to:

```
Dim FoundRange As Object
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the ID values are stored as text in the worksheet, either with a cell type of Text or with an apostrophe/single-quote in front of the number, you may need to format the ID as string. With the further assumption that eventually you may want to pass the ID via parameter to the procedure, give this a try:

`Set FoundRange = .Cells.Find(CStr(260707))`

That will also allow you to replace the constant number with a variable if desired.

Comment: `.Find` takes a `Variant` as the `What` parameter, and it can be "a string or any Microsoft Excel data type".  This code will explicitly cast a `Long` literal to a `String`, then *implicitly* cast it to a `Variant`. The end result is pretty much the same as the OP's code.

Comment: That solved it! thank you. Now, I am getting the NTlogin and Role variables return as blank, when they should be whatever the text value in those cells are. Is there something else I need to change with the way I defined those variables?

Comment: @Andre I'm not sure if this will solve it or not, but I use the _.Value_ property instead of .Text. I remember there's a subtle difference between the two, but can't remember right now what it is.  
`NTlogin = .Cells(FoundRange.Rows, 1).Value`
`Role = .Cells(FoundRange.Rows, 4).Value`

Comment: @Comintern I almost wish it were that easy. Variants actually have types also, depending on what is stored in the variable, and a _string_ Variant often doesn't match a _numeric_ Variant. The msdn [Variant Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx) page: "Generally, numeric Variant data is maintained in its original data type within the Variant." And if you have a way to have VLOOKUP() find a number in cells either stored as text or as a numeric value automatically, I'd love to hear that, because I'm always having to switch it manually from one type to the other.

Comment: @GlennFromIowa - Yes, I know all about [Variants](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits/11786/variant#t=201608060036163968204).  Point taken though - it would be a Variant(String) instead of a Variant(Long).  That's why I usually roll my own lookups instead of using the Excel ones.  ;-)