# Retrieve data on Excel from Word VBA using Worksheetfunction

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to automatically fill in tables in a MS word file by retrieving data in various excel tables. In order to properly interact with Excel it would be very handy to work with worksheetfunction. Yet since the macro is in MS Word I am getting blocked. Any way to access it? Cheers

```
Dim src As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim t As String
Dim c As Integer
    
t = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
t = Left(t, Len(t) - 1)

Set src = workbooks.Open("https://collab.ext.../asd.xlsx", True, True)
Set ws = src.Worksheets("Data")

c = worksheetfunction.Match(t, ws.Range("A1:AA1"), False)

src.Close
Set src = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you have a reference set to the Excel Object Library under Tools > References?

Comment: You don't seem to have an Excel application object you're working with?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747963/using-word-vba-to-automate-excel-i-get-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch-when

Comment: `t = Left(t, Len(t) - 1)` should be `t = Left(t, Len(t) - 2)` - the "end of cell marker" in Word is two characters, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Williams thanks for your help. Corrected code below:

```
Dim oXL As Object
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim wbPath As String
Dim t As String
Dim c As Integer

Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Visible = False

wbPath = "https://collab.ext...asd.xlsx"
    
t = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
t = Left(t, Len(t) - 2)

Set oWB = oXL.workbooks.Open(wbPath, True, True)
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Data")
    
c = oXL.worksheetfunction.Match(t, oWS.Range("A1:AA3"), False)

oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
oXL.Application.Quit
Set oXL = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing
Set oWS = Nothing
```